# php to execute python which requests to a https link fails

Tags: php, python, exec

Hello I have my python file which shows the sell value of bittrex:

```
import requests
import time
import hashlib


print("---------------------------new program --------------------------------")


r = requests.get(url='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-XRP&type=both')

print(r.json()["result"]["sell"][0]["Rate"])
```

The python above executed correctly and show the value when execute in console.

And I have a php page to execute and show the result of the price of XRP from bittrex

```
<?php
  ob_start();
    $output = shell_exec('python3 /home/dramasea/Desktop/mypython.py');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>";

    ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Can I know why it only shows `-------new program-------` on the webpage but not the value of the price as it shown when executed in console

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Before PHP 5.4 there was a safe mode that would inhibit the use of shell_exec and other functions if enabled: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php

Comment: @mega6382 u can run python on the console first to see the result difference than when it is run from the browser

Comment: @shmee i am running php7.0

Comment: @dramasea OK, just realized that you actually see the "new-program" line anyway. Maybe there's other errors? Try redirecting stderr to stdout to see potential error messages.

Comment: @shmee There shouldnt be any error because when i execute the python solely in the console it does not show the error

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason to use Python here. Just PHP is enough :

```
<?php
$o = file_get_contents('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=BTC-XRP&type=both');
echo(json_decode($o)->result->sell[0]->Rate);
?>
```

Comment: I know there is no need python, but there are much more to be executed in python as my previous code base is in python